# Segmentation fault at free()

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I do free() in the delete function of the following linked list implementation. Please take a look and tell me where I am going wrong. When I run this program with valgrind, there is no seg. fault, it runs fine. So I am not able to figure out the problem.

```
typedef struct node {
    char name[100];
    int id;
    struct node* next;
} Node;

void insert(Node** p, char* _name, int _id)
{
    Node *temp, *prev;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->next = NULL;
    strcpy(temp->name,_name);
    temp->id = _id;

    if(*p == NULL) {
            *p = temp;
    }
    else {
            for(prev = *p; prev->next!=NULL; prev=prev->next);
            prev->next=temp;
    }
}

/* Delete entry
  @params p    first element
       _id     ID to delete
*/
void delete_by_id(Node** p, int _id) {
    Node *temp, *prev;
    prev = NULL;
    for(temp = *p; temp!= NULL; prev = temp, temp=temp->next) {
            if(temp->id == _id) {
                printf("Deleting entry with id: %d\n", temp->id);
                if(prev == NULL)
                     *p = temp->next;
                else
                     prev->next= temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return;
            }
    }     
}
```

Here is part of the code from the main program:

```
Node* p;  
int main() {
      ...
      ...
      buf[rval]=0;
      char* tokens = strtok(buf, "+");
      char* strArray[5]; /* up-to 5 words can be stored */
      int n = 0;
      while (tokens)
      {
        strArray[n] = malloc(strlen(tokens) + 1);
        strcpy(strArray[n++], tokens);
        tokens = strtok(NULL, "+");
      }
      int type = 0;
      if(strcmp(strArray[0], "1") == 0)
            type = 1;
      else
            type = 2;
      char* name = "";  
      if(type == 1) {
            name = strArray[1];
            insert(&p, name, clients[i]);
            display(&p);
      } else {
            name = strArray[1];
            rval = search(&p, name);
            if(rval) { 
                delete_by_id(&p, rval);
                display(&p);
            }
      }

      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
        if (strArray[i]) // check for null data 
            free(strArray[i]);
      }
      ...
      ...
}

int search(Node** p, char* _name) {
    Node *temp;
    for (temp = *p; temp!= NULL; temp = temp->next) {
            if (strcmp((char *)temp->name, _name)==0) {
                    printf("Name matched: %s\n", temp->name);
                    return temp->id;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind is complaining about the malloc and free used for strArray but not for the linked list.

Comment: It would be worth showing a short (10-20 line) `main()` program that shows how you are allocating and freeing the list using the functions shown.

Comment: You should use strncpy to avoid overrunning node.name.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I have added the main() code, please take a look.

Comment: You don't need to check for `NULL` when freeing a pointer. `free(NULL);` is well-defined behaviour (it does nothing, `free` is defined to ignore the `NULL` pointer).

Comment: why do you do char* name = "";  
      if(type == 1) {
            name = strArray[1];...
?
char *name = ""; creates string literal that is readonly (to be exact undefined behavior, but mostly hardcoded into program to unreadable chunk of memory).

Comment: Your `while (tokens)` loop does not ensure there are five or fewer tokens to work on. You don't ensure that the `strArray` pointers are zeroed before you start using the array, but your freeing code relies on the uninitialized values being zero. Your freeing loop should count to `n` instead of 5. Freeing random garbage is a problem that could cause segmentation faults. You can help your diagnosis of where the problem is by inserting judicious print statements to check that you're getting what you expect to get: in the `while (tokens)` loop and in the `free()` loop, and elsewhere too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I got rid of `strArray` and the malloc and free for it. The program is working now. Thank u so much!!

Answer (score 6):

Print out the addresses returned by `malloc()`, and also print out the value of `temp` immediately before the call to `free()`.  Make sure that what's being passed to `free()` matches what you expect.  If somehow you are passing a pointer to `free()` that didn't come from `malloc()`, you can encounter problems like you are seeing.

There's also a possibility that the function `delete_by_id()` is using an invalid pointer.  The `p` parameter is dereferenced before it's checked for `NULL`.  I recommend walking through the function in your debugger and making sure that all of the pointers look as you expect them to look.

Answer (score 5):

Let your program dump core and analyze the core in GDB:

```
gdb -c yourprog.core yourprog
```

then do a full backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt full
```

This will show you where exactly the reason for your segfault is and what values were passed to the function.

(edit) Oh, and compile your program with the GCC `-g` switch to have debugging information.

Answer (score 3):

Run your program through valgrind. Segfaults on free are usually due to writes outside of the allocated memory (which overwrites/corrupts the wrappers that the system places before/after allocated memory). Valgrind is usually the easiest way to find out when the writes in question happens.

Comment: I used valgrind, but then the program runs fine. There is no seg. fault happening and valgrind doesnt seem to point out any memory errors. The fault is occurring only when I run the program by itself.

Comment: In that case, I have to agree with Jonathan Leffler: Please show us how you call the functions in your code. If you haven't tried it, run it through valgrind when compiled with optimizations. Memory errors will somtimes not show themselves until you compile with optimizations.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Leo. I have added the main() code, please take a look.

Comment: @ddd: Show us how you invoked valgrind. For starters try `valgrind -v --leak-check=full ./executable` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks @dreamlax. I tried that command and this is what I got: ==11512== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11512==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11512==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 191 bytes allocated
==11512== 
==11512== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11512== 
==11512== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==11512== ERROR SUMMARY: 109 errors from 21 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)

Comment: Sometimes when I run the code with insertion and deletion of more nodes, valgrind shows more number of frees than allocs, and it says all heap blocks were freed -- no leaks possible

Comment: @ddd: So you aren't leaking memory but it still says you have **109 errors** which could mean you are trying to access memory outside of the range you have asked for, etc.

Comment: Yep, like dreamlax is saying, you are probably not leaking memory, but that is not why you are getting segfaults on free in any case. The errors in the valgrind log are what you should be looking at. You are probably looking for an off by one write or similar since you are getting a segfault on free and not on an actual write.